# Extract and sum muitple occurences of numbers in cells

Tags: regex, google-sheets, formulas

Let's say that I have a row which looks like this (`|` are the cell separators):

```
1h foo | 0.5h bar, 0.5h baz | 6h blah, 1h bah
```

I would like to sum all the hours on a row, so the example above would output 9.

This is what I have so far, but I don't know how to sum multiple occurrences of numbers within a cell (like `0.5h bar, 0.5h baz`). Any suggestions?

`=arrayformula(sum(if(isNumber(B3:F3),B3:F3,iferror(value(regexextract(B3:F3,"\d+(?:\.\d+)?")),0))))`

Answer (score 1):

To the first argument of REGEXTRACT apply JOIN using a comma, then SPLIT by comma. Let say that the below data is on A1:C1

```
1h foo | 0.5h bar, 0.5h baz | 6h blah, 1h bah
```

If you apply this to B3

```
=ArrayFormula(split(join(",",A1:C1),","))
```

Then your formula works just fine.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting `Array arguments to IF are different sizes` when I use it in my snippet above. Maybe you could show me an example on how to integrate it?